# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox sidebar thinner when using position:fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, css-position

I'm building a sidebar using the grid system in Bootstrap 4, and the Flexbox utility. For the most part, I have it working, except that I would like to have the sidebar be "static," that is, it should not move when the user scrolls on the page next to it.

I attempted to do this by adding position:fixed to it, but when I did that, the column the sidebar was in was reduced in size to the length of the longest string that was there.

How do I make the sidebar stay fixed in place, while maintaining column width?

Here's my code: (It's a React app, so "class" is replaced with "className")

Parent component:

```
{ this.state.isLoggedIn ?
   <div className="row h-100">
      <div className="col-2 no-padding-right">
         <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div className="col-10 no-padding-left">
         <Main />
      </div>
   </div> :
   <Main />
}
```

The sidebar itself:

```
<div className="d-flex h-100 align-items-start sidebar-left flex-column sidebar-background sidebar-text">
                <div className="p-2">
                    Week 11
                </div>
                <div className="mb-auto align-self-stretch h-100 p-2">Leagues/Teams</div>
                <div className="p-2">Current Features</div>
                <div className="p-2">Feature Request</div>
                <div className="p-2">Settings</div>
                <div className="p-2">Billing</div>
                <div className="p-2">Log Out</div>
            </div>
```

And the relevant piece of CSS:

```
.sidebar-left {
    padding-top: 83px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want a proper answer, add a working code snippet within the question that reproduce the issue you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `max-width` to the `sidebar-left` is equal to how much your `col` have.

```
.sidebar-left {
  max-width: 16.666667%;
}
```

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-left {
  font: 13px Verdana;
  padding-top: 83px;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  max-width: 16.666667%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.p-2 {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row h-100">
  <div class="col-2 no-padding-right">
    <div class="d-flex h-100 align-items-start sidebar-left flex-column sidebar-background sidebar-text">
      <div class="p-2">
        Week 11
      </div>
      <div class="mb-auto align-self-stretch h-100 p-2">Leagues/Teams</div>
      <div class="p-2">Current Features</div>
      <div class="p-2">Feature Request</div>
      <div class="p-2">Settings</div>
      <div class="p-2">Billing</div>
      <div class="p-2">Log Out</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-10 no-padding-left">
    <div class="main"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```